# How can you create a html-table where the header (th) collapse all the columns (td)?

Tags: html

I want to create a html-table with on th-header and 4 cells per row.

How do you do that?
The header has a width of 100% and the cells have a width of 40%, 10%, 40%, 10%.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr><th width="100%">Header</th></tr>
  <tr>
     <td width="40%">text</td>
     <td width="10%">value</td>
     <td width="40%">text</td>
     <td width="10%">value</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
     <td width="40%">text</td>
     <td width="10%">value</td>
     <td width="40%">text</td>
     <td width="10%">value</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
     <td width="40%">text</td>
     <td width="10%">value</td>
     <td width="40%">text</td>
     <td width="10%">value</td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

[image]

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `colspan` attribute.:

```
<tr><th colspan="4">Header</th></tr>
```

The `colspan` attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates on how many columns the cell extends. Its default value is 1; if its value is set to 0, it does extend until the end of the , eventually implicitly defined, the cell belongs to. Values higher than 1000 are clipped down to 1000.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/th

The developer [docs on mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) are the best around. Start there next time.

Comment: It doesn't work. And in w3schools they say: "Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01." by width.

Comment: **w3schools sucks** seriously. So much so it has it's own website explaining all the reasons it sucks: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: While [w3schools do suck](http://w3fools.com/) they say nothing close to colspan not being supported in HTML5. Where did you grab that quotation?

Comment: Okay it was something in the css in a class i defined. "float: left;"

Comment: DO NOT FLOAT TABLE ELEMENTS. Also define widths like `style="width: 40%"` not like `width="40%"`. But frankly if the content of that cell needs more space it'll jack up the widths regardless.

Comment: I forgot to remove it. Before I had tried something else than using a table.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the tag caption to create a header for a table. or use property colspan="number of colls"